# ES6 How to handle static property of sub class in super class

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, ecmascript-6

```
class Line extends Shape {
    static howToDrag = { point: 0, update: 'xy' }
    static config = { color: 'white' }
    render() {
        console.log('render based on this.config', this.config)
    }
}

class Shape {
    constructor({ config }) {
        this.constructor.howToDrag = expandProperty1(this.constructor.howToDrag)
        this.config = config || this.constructor.config
    }
    drag() {
        console.log('drag based on this.constructor.howToDrag ', this.constructor.howToDrag)
    }

}

function expandProperty1({ point, update }) {
    if (typeof update === 'string') {
        return {
            point,
            update: {
                [point]: update
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code, If you can understand what I am doing, skip the following explanation and provided some suggestions on what is the better way to make use of OOP because the current implementation is pretty wired from my perspective.

Check out http://canvas-chart.herokuapp.com/ to see what I am doing and I will explain the code above.

Let us talk about the static property `config` first. `config` should belong to each instance, i.e. each instance should have its own `config`, why I put it as `static`? The reason is that there is some common logic related to config, i.e. it should be the value passed from the constructor, otherwise, it has the default value. By setting the `config` as `static`, I am able to implement such common logic in 'Base' class, rather than write it over and over again in each `Derived` class

The other concern is `howToDrag`, it is a real `static`.However the `static` is used by base class but defined in the derived class, is it a normal thing? What is more, the static property in the derived class is mutated in the base class.

The current make logical sense but I always wonder if it is the way to do OOP because it relies on the fact `this.constructor` is base class point to the derived class.

Comment: No `extends`, no subclass.

Comment: @StackSlave code edited

Comment: `ShapeInstance.drag()` would only work if you called it after you call your `new` instance of `Line`, so it's a poor design.

Comment: "*there is some common logic related to config*" - I don't see much logic related to your config, but shared logic doesn't necessitate a static property. Sure, for storing a subclass-specific default value it's fine. "*the static is used by base class but defined in the derived class*" - you do that for `config` as well. Your `Shape` superclass should probably have its own default config though. (Or be considered abstract). "*The static property in the derived class is mutated in the base class.*" - this is a huge issue. Why do you do that? Just put the `expandProperty1` call in the subclass.

Comment: @StackSlave you are right, `shapeInstance.drag()` make no sense at all, only `lineInstance.drag()` make sense

Comment: @Bergi "I don't see much logic related to your config" The logic is simple: if no config provided to the constructor, initialized using the default one. But the problem is how you write such logic only *once* without putting config as static

Comment: *Why do you do that? Just put the expandProperty1 call in the subclass*, the same problem. if I call `expandProperty1` in the subclass. I should write that line in every subclass, if  I put it in the superclass. It only write once! @Bergi

Comment: Actually, here is the dilemma. If I put the properties as for instance properties, it makes more sense in OOP, but I need to write the same code in every instance. On the other hand, if I put them as a static property, I only need to write code once but look wired in the OOP perspective.  @Bergi

Comment: @Guichi I mean writing `static howToDrag = expandProperty1({ point: 0, update: 'xy' })` in the subclass, not repeating the line in the constructor. You already abstracted out the logic into the callable `expandProperty1` function anyway. (If you would prefer, you could make that a static method of the parent class).

Comment: @Bergi I suppose there may be some OOP pattern and I am doing some research on the OOP design pattern currently. If you know some pattern relevant, please point it out, much appreciated

Comment: @Bergi even though *I already abstracted out the logic into the callable expandProperty1* it still need to be called in **every** subclass, but if I call that in the superclass. I can do it **only once**

Comment: @Bergi Why a correct business logic looks so wired in OOP? I strongly suspect there should be some establish a way to handle this. i.e. only write the code only, at the same time, considered as a decent OOP design

Comment: @Guichi It's not much harm to call a method - you also need to define the property in every subclass with the custom values, it's not exactly boilerplate. If you insist using it only in the superclass, at least do it inside the `drag` method where the `howToDrag` value is actually used - do not mutate the subclass, and do not mutate static properties from the constructor.

Comment: @Guichi Btw it's not exactly clear from the example code what the business logic is or what is "correct" about it. Also I don't think "wired" is the right word you're looking for, but I'm not a native speaker. Also, do you have a non-OOP version of the code that looks better to you, for comparison? To choose a proper design we would need to know more about your use case, e.g. how these classes will be instantiated, when, where and how often their methods are called, how many subclasses you expect and how they could differ.

Comment: @Bergi The point I try to make is **"OOP is not capable to handle trivial use case"**. Forget about my use case or what is "correct". The more general use case it **"Initialize the instance in superclass based on static property in the subclass, by initialize, I mean both instance variable and static variable"**

Comment: @Guichi best practises (OOP or not) are that initialisation of static variables should be separated from initialisation of instances. But if you don't like OOP, use another paradigm that you like better, nobody will scold you for that.

Comment: @Guichi Without a use case, I cannot suggest any suitable alternative. If you don't need help with a particular problem, what exactly is your question?

Comment: My use case is valid, what i mean is the there is more general use case than my specific use case @b